# camel thread pooling query

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-camel, threadpool

I am working on camel thread pooling and using pooling size and max pooling size. my understanding is each request will be handled by one thread and if request > pool size, new one thread will be created in pool using max pool size. To ensure my understanding I did below POC.

```
public class FileMoverRoute extends SpringRouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        CamelContext context = getContext();
        ExecutorService executorService = new ThreadPoolBuilder(context)
                .poolSize(1).maxPoolSize(10).maxQueueSize(100).build("CustomThreadPool");

        from("file://C:/from").log("Received ${body}:${threadName}").threads().executorService(executorService)
                .log("Processing ${body}:${threadName}").process(new FileProcessor()).to("file://C:/to");
    }

}

public class FileProcessor implements Processor{

    public void process(Exchange exc) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> headerMap = exc.getIn().getHeaders();
        System.out.println(" sleep for minute");
        TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(1);
        System.out.println(" woke up"+headerMap);
    }

}
```

I gave 1 min sleep in File processor. If I put 1 file(1.txt) inside from folder I could see received & Processing log in console. If put next 2 files(2.txt,3.txt) files inside from folder. I could see received log for 2 files not processing log. since my max pool size is 10, camel should increase threads and pick the file.

1. why new threads are not getting created in pool ?
2. Why new files are not getting picked ?
3. How to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 4):

As you have set poolsize as 1 , only one thread will be used to process.

Threads are created as follows

1. If thread pool is smaller than the poolSize, a new thread is created to process.
2. If jobs are less than maxQueueSize, then job is placed on the queue to wait for a free thread.
3. If queue is full and the thread pool has less than maxPoolSize threads instantiated, a new thread is created to process the Job.

You can test by yourself by reducing the QueueSize

Comment: Yes, I changed **maxQueueSize(-1)**. it is working as per expectation. Then , to create new thread for new job . always it should be -1. please confirm or is there any way . it will be helpful

Comment: Jobs will be Queued when all the thread are busy processing the jobs. If you have  enough number of Threads to process you can set the Queue size to -1 and then new job will be created for each job, until you hit the max PoolSize.